# ExceptionInInitializerError когда обновил Pushwoosh

Tags: java, android, robolectric

**Добрый день всем.**

Я обновил библиотеку pushwoosh в build.gradle и после этого все тесты на robolectric стали падать с такой **ошибкой**:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.pushwoosh.location.geofencer.GeofenceReceiver.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callConstructor(ReflectionHelpers.java:321)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.ShadowImpl.newInstanceOf(ShadowImpl.java:20)
    at org.robolectric.shadow.api.Shadow.newInstanceOf(Shadow.java:35)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowApplication.registerBroadcastReceivers(ShadowApplication.java:138)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowApplication.bind(ShadowApplication.java:127)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter.bind(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:71)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:107)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.beforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:290)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:203)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:109)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:36)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$1.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.pushwoosh.location.d.a.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.pushwoosh.location.internal.a.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 33 more
```

**Ниже мой тестовый файл:**

```
@RunWith(CustomRobolectricRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
@FragmentScope
public class LentaPresenterTest {

    @Mock
    private LentaItem lentaItemMock;
    @Mock
    private ChampionatRepository championatDataRepositoryMock;
    @Mock
    private CommentsRepository commentsRepositoryMock;
    @Mock
    private LocalRepository localRepositoryMock;
    @Inject
    BookmarkRepository bookmarkRepository;
    @Mock
    private LentaView lentaViewMock;
    @Mock
    private Exception exceptionMock;
    @Inject
    Context context;
    @Inject
    LocalRepository localRepository;
    @Mock
    private NetworkInfoManager networkInfoManager;
    @Inject
    protected LentaPresenter lentaPresenterTest;

    private List<LentaItem> lentaItemListMock;
    private Observable<GetLentaInteractor.LentaResponce> observable;
    private Observable<Boolean> isShowFontObservable;

    private TestScheduler testScheduler = Schedulers.test();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        TestApp.getTestComponent().createTestActivityComponent(new TestActivityModule(mock(Activity.class))).
                createTestFragmentComponent(new TestFragmentModule(mock(Fragment.class))).inject(this);
        lentaPresenterTest = spy(lentaPresenterTest);

        assert lentaPresenterTest.getLentaInteractor != null;

        lentaItemListMock = new ArrayList<>();
        lentaItemListMock.add(lentaItemMock);

        observable = Observable.just(new GetLentaInteractor.LentaResponce(lentaItemListMock, 2));
        lentaPresenterTest.setView(lentaViewMock);
        lentaPresenterTest.getLentaInteractor = spy(new GetLentaInteractor(championatDataRepositoryMock, commentsRepositoryMock, localRepositoryMock, bookmarkRepository, networkInfoManager) {

            @Override
            public Subscription execute(LentaFilter lentaFilter, Subscriber<LentaResponce> subscriber) {
                return observable.subscribe(subscriber);
            }
        });

        lentaPresenterTest.isShowRatingViewInteractor = spy(new IsShowRatingViewInteractor(localRepository, context) {
            @Override
            protected Observable<Boolean> buildObservable() {
                return isShowFontObservable;
            }
        });

        lentaPresenterTest.isShowRatingViewInteractor.setJobScheduler(testScheduler);
        lentaPresenterTest.isShowRatingViewInteractor.setIuScheduler(testScheduler);
    }


    @Test
    public void interactorOnErrorTest() {
        observable = Observable.error(exceptionMock);

        lentaPresenterTest.initialize();

        verify(lentaViewMock, times(1)).startProgress();
        verify(lentaViewMock, times(1)).setSelectedSportsKinds(anyList());
        verify(lentaViewMock, times(1)).showLayoutWithInformation();
        verify(lentaViewMock, times(1)).stopProgress();
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(lentaViewMock);
    }

    @Test
    public void interactorOnErrorTest_showTop() {
        observable = observable.concatWith(Observable.<GetLentaInteractor.LentaResponce>error(exceptionMock));

        lentaPresenterTest.initialize();
        verify(lentaViewMock, times(1)).startProgress();
        verify(lentaViewMock, times(1)).setSelectedSportsKinds(anyList());
        verify(lentaViewMock, times(1)).inflateData(anyList());
        verify(lentaViewMock, times(1)).hideBottomErrorMessage();
        verify(lentaViewMock, times(1)).showTopErrorMessage();
        verify(lentaViewMock, times(1)).stopProgress();
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(lentaViewMock);
    }

    @Test
    public void interactorOnNextTest_first_request_true() {
        isShowFontObservable = Observable.just(true);
        lentaPresenterTest.lentaFilter = LentaFilter.EMPTY;
        lentaPresenterTest.initialize();

        testScheduler.triggerActions();
        verify(lentaPresenterTest.getLentaInteractor, times(1)).execute(any(LentaFilter.class), any(Subscriber.class));
        verify(lentaPresenterTest.isShowRatingViewInteractor, times(1)).execute(any(Subscriber.class));
        verify(lentaViewMock, times(1)).inflateData(lentaItemListMock);
    }

    @Test
    public void interactorOnNextTest_first_request_false() {
        isShowFontObservable = Observable.just(true);
        lentaPresenterTest.lentaFilter = LentaFilter.EMPTY.lentaBefore("before id");
        lentaPresenterTest.initialize();

        testScheduler.triggerActions();
        verify(lentaPresenterTest.getLentaInteractor, times(1)).execute(any(LentaFilter.class), any(Subscriber.class));
        verify(lentaPresenterTest.isShowRatingViewInteractor, times(1)).execute(any(Subscriber.class));
        verify(lentaViewMock, times(1)).appendData(lentaItemListMock);
    }
}
```

**Мой build.gradle файл:**

```
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.3.2'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.3.2'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-play-services:3.1'
```

До обновления pushwoosh тесты отрабатывали все и корректно, сейчас же картина ровно до наоборот.

За помощь заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем нужно было **добавить в контейнер**(в моем случае выбрал hashset, чтобы не было дубликатов, плюс так посоветовали по ссылке ниже) **злокачественный пакет(класс)**, который вызывал данную ошибку и не давать ему инициализироваться через ваш androidManifest(у меня он инициализируется в custom robolectric test runner).

C полным описанием решения можно ознакомиться по ссылке ниже:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509996/exceptionininitializererror-when-updated-pushwoosh